# Windows Server Backup Scheduling

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, scheduled-task, backup-restoration, windows-server-backup

Windows Server 2008 R2.

I know it's possible to schedule a backup, but is it possible to schedule a **recovery**?

I have already backed up my server using the 'Backup Once' feature. Now I'd like to schedule the recovery of this to another drive, either during the night or over the weekend when I won't be physically at the server.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You probably could with task scheduler and wbadmin.  Something like

```
wbadmin start recovery -version:03/31/2017-09:00 -itemType:Volume -items:d: -recoverytarget:\\servername\share
```

would probably do the trick.

(You can get version information with `wbadmin get versions`.)